# ASP.NET Text Box doesn't get focus when page is redirected from a Silverlight page

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-chrome, silverlight

I am stuck in a very strange issue that happens in the **Chrome browser only**.

I have a Silverlight page with a button on it. On clicking that button I want to open an ASPX page with a text box on it having attribute autofocus applied. But whenever I redirect from Silverlight page to ASPX page, the text box is never get focused on Chrome browser. Did anyone face such issue before?

Below are the version information associated

1. Google Chrome : 41.0.2272.89 m
2. .NET Framework : 4.5.1
3. Silverlight : 5.0

**Code Snippet Silverlight ( MAIN.XAML File)**

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Button Content="Go to Default page" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="161,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156"/>
    </Grid>
```

**Code Snippet Silverlight ( MAIN.XAML.CS File )**

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("Default.aspx", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

**Code Snippet DEFAULT.ASPX page**

```
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" ClientIDMode="Static" autofocus/>
    </div>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

instead of autofocus, would TabIndex="0" work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Wazz, but it didn't help me either.